# Get record Count from table using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Delivery management, there is delivery status "Delivered" and "Pending". I want the count of total records of each.
I need the answer in following formate

---

```
|Deliverd | Pending|
-------------------|
|   0    |   9     |
-------------------
```

I am trying by following query, But not getting result as I want.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fm_delivery_management WHERE status=0)
AS Deliverd, (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM fm_delivery_management
WHERE status=1) AS Pending
FROM fm_delivery_management
```

by this query I getting following result

```
|Deliverd|Pending|
------------------
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
|   0    |   9   |
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

In SQL data should be in a normalised structure as it makes queries much simpler. The normalised results for your example would be given by...

```
SELECT
  status, 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  fm_delivery_management
GROUP BY
  status
```

This format means that if any new status starts being used it is immediately included in the results, without any change to the code.

If you make this as a function it also becomes reusable by other code that you might write in the future.

It is short, fast, maintainable, adaptable, reusable, and idiomatic SQL.

People often try to force SQL to create pivoted results like yours. And it is quite easy to do, I'll give an example below. But it's generally a bad idea. Pivoting and formatting don't generally belong in SQL. It makes the code less generalised, normally longer and harder to maintain or adapt, very often slower, and all together worse from a software development perspective.

If you really really must do it the bad way though, you don't need nested sub-queries. Just use CASE statements to filter what you are aggregating.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 END), 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM
  fm_delivery_management
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "FROM fm_delivery_management" at the end of your query. Otherwise it will repeat for all the records(rows) of that table .
Just use

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fm_delivery_management WHERE status=0)
AS Deliverd, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fm_delivery_management WHERE 
status=1) AS Pending
```

Comment: Still uses two unnecessary sub queries, for longer and slower code. Just use SUM(CASE)...

Comment: Yes. can be written as - SELECT SUM(case when status=0 then 1 else 0 end) AS Deliverd, SUM(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end ) AS Pending
FROM fm_delivery_management